# Optimizing Google Cloud Function for Scalability with Large Excel to CSV Conversion

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I'm using a Google Cloud Function to convert large Excel files to CSV. However, I'm facing performance and scalability issues. Here's the context:

**Current Setup**:

- **Region**: `eu`
- **Memory allocated**: `2 GB`
- **Timeout**: `480 seconds`
- **Minimum Instances**: `0`
- **Maximum Instances**: `4`
- The Excel file is currently `110 MB` but has been growing over the past 5 months and is expected to reach up to `500 MB` within 2 years.

**Challenge**:
The conversion process is nearing the Cloud Function's timeout (taking around 8 minutes out of the 9 minutes available), and the post-conversion processing takes an additional 4 minutes. Originally, with a smaller file size, it was working fine with this configuration.

**Code**:
I'm currently using the `openpyxl` library for conversion. Here's my code:

```py
if table_id == 'CONVERTED_TABLE':
    delimiter = ";"
    excel_file = blob_source.download_as_bytes()
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=io.BytesIO(excel_file), read_only=True)
    ws = wb.active
    csv_file = "CONVERTED_TABLE" + file.replace(".xlsx", "") + ".csv"
    csv_bytes = io.BytesIO()

    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        # Skip empty rows
        if all(cell.value is None for cell in row):
            continue

        row_data = [str(cell.value).replace("\n", " ").replace("\r", " ") if cell.value is not None else "" for cell in row]
        csv_bytes.write((delimiter.join(row_data) + "\n").encode('ISO-8859-1'))

    csv_bytes.seek(0)
    bucket.blob(csv_file).upload_from_file(csv_bytes, content_type='text/csv')
    
    wb.close()

print(f"Finished convert_excel_to_csv")
gc.collect()
```

How can I optimize my Cloud Function's configuration to handle the growing file size and ensure scalability for the next 2 years or at least the next year?

Is there a way to optimize the above code for better performance without significantly increasing costs? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use Cloud Functions gen2 to extend the timeout to 1h, and optimize your code to be multi-thread compliant (I don't know how to do in Python! Only in Go) and set multiple CPU on your instance. You can also use a more efficient language like go for compute intensive processing.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thank you for the insightful suggestion. However, I'm aiming to find a solution with gen1 to minimize the need for extensive code migration

Comment: Add --gen2 to deploy in gen2 with your command line, nothing more. About code restructuring, you can't do the same thing in sequence than in parallel. Without redesign, you will be limited soon or later.